# Why am I getting the error "frame processor crashed"?

Tags: java, android, firebase, image, android-studio

I am creating an app which will detect faces in real time and also detect face landmarks in a photo using [Google's ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android)(the post of Firebase ML Kit). I have obtained the functionality for the landmark detection, but am struggling with real time detection.

I am not going to include the whole program(as it's over 500 lines of code), but rather a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

In my debugger, the code crashes at this line of code:

```
Task<List<Face>> result = faceDetector.process(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Face>>() {
```

and invokes the failure listener attached to `faceDetector.process(image)`

It goes into the CameraView class with the exception "Frame Processor Crashed":

```
 @Override
    public void dispatchFrame(@NonNull final Frame frame) {
        // The getTime() below might crash if developers incorrectly release
        // frames asynchronously.
        LOG.v("dispatchFrame:", frame.getTime(), "processors:", mFrameProcessors.size());
        if (mFrameProcessors.isEmpty()) {
            // Mark as released. This instance will be reused.
            frame.release();
        } else {
            // Dispatch this frame to frame processors.
            mFrameProcessingExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    LOG.v("dispatchFrame: executing. Passing", frame.getTime(),
                            "to processors.");
                    for (FrameProcessor processor : mFrameProcessors) {
                        try {
                            processor.process(frame);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            LOG.w("Frame processor crashed:", e);
                        }
                    }
                    frame.release();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The image which I'm processing is the InputImage as documented by the [Google ML Kit documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android):

```
int width = frame.getSize().getWidth();
        int height = frame.getSize().getHeight();

        byte[] byteArray = frame.getData();
        InputImage image = InputImage.fromByteArray(
                //frame.getData()
                byteArray,
                width,
                height,
                //rotation
                (cameraFacing == Facing.FRONT) ? 90 : 270,
                //image format
                InputImage.IMAGE_FORMAT_YV12 // or IMAGE_FORMAT_YV12

        );
```

***What may be going wrong here?***

> ***Context information***
>
> - I am using the [CameraView library](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) which supports Camera1 and Camera2
> - I am also using the [Crop Image library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

Thanks!

Comment: what is the error after the text "frame processer crashed: "

Comment: Hi, it's just the dispatchError method which isn't too relevant. Instead, I added the full code block of `dispatchFrame()`